# How to properly form an API route using Laravel Resource?(with relationships)

Tags: php, laravel, api, resources

I'm confused on how to create my routings on my backend API program.

I'm using this as my basis : https://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/

I wanted a suggestion,opinion or solutions if my routings are correct.

`example.com/users/1/employees/1`
creates

```
[
    data : {
        username : 'Username1',
        email : 'email@example.com',
        employeesData : {
           fullname : 'John Mcain',
           birthDate : '1990-01-01',
           address : '123 Street'
        }
    }

]
```

*please do note that these came from two different tables in my database

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I need opinions if my route is correct

Answer (score 0):

If user and employee data are relational then the route is correct.
If they are not related it is better to make separate route.

Comment: How about if i want to exclude the employee info?

Comment: Then omit the employee part.